# FastAPI route - TypeError: root() missing 1 required positional argument when using request object

Tags: python, fastapi

I get this error:

> TypeError: root() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

stack trace:

> ! Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/assistant-backend/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 408, in run_asgi
> result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
> File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/assistant-backend/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 84, in **call**
> return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
> File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/assistant-backend/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 1106, in **call**
> await super().**call**(scope, receive, send)
> File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/assistant-backend/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 122, in **call**
> await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
> File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/assistant-backend/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in **call**
> raise exc
> File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/assistant-backend/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in **call**
> await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
> File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/assistant-backend/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 79, in **call**
> raise exc
> File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/assistant-backend/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 68, in **call**
> await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
> File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/assistant-backend/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 20, in **call**
> raise e
> File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/assistant-backend/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 17, in **call**
> await self.app(scope, receive, send)
> File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/assistant-backend/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 718, in **call**
> await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
> File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/assistant-backend/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 276, in handle
> await self.app(scope, receive, send)
> File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/assistant-backend/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 66, in app

Which I'm able to reproduce with this simple bit of code:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
app = FastAPI()

@app.route("/{full_path:path}")
async def root(full_path: str, request: Request):
    print(request.method ,full_path)
    return "HIYO"
```

I need to access the full path and request object inside the route, and as far as I've been able to find, this is the way to do this. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

I run the script using `uvicorn main:app`

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code states that this decorator is no longer documented and should be avoided.
[image]

Use `@app.get(...)` instead.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/{full_path:path}")
async def root(full_path: str, request: Request):
    print(request.method ,full_path)
    return "HIYO"
```

Comment: thanks for finding that. That was my interim workaround but bit of a pain as I have to duplicate code for get, post, put, delete, patch, options...